# Remove Ubuntu 13.04 and put Windows 7

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu and chose option 'something else' and i created partitions, but now i cant boot to windows but when i re-install Ubuntu there is an option to install it along with windows  7. I want to completely remove Ubuntu 13.04 but i cant i need windows 7 for school work i tried BIOS, Image discs ISO file, but still only thing i can do is to install UBuntu 13.04 but not version 12, 11 nor 10.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you need to restore Bootloader. Without it, you wont be able to boot Windows 7.

Now, you either install Ubuntu, and install this program named boot repair. You will have two OSes.

Or you need to find some live cd solution which can fix boot loader. I am sure if you google that "live cd boot loader fix" or something like that, you will find a solution.